# How do I refer to arguments of a function when the function is passed in as a parameter?

Tags: javascript

New to JavaScript, so give me some leeway.

I'm currently trying to simulate contracts in JavaScript.  There are preconditions and postconditions which can be defined when you declare a function.  I've compiled a simple setup of how it should work below.

Function mult() has a few contracts which should check if the two inputs are numbers and should check if the resulting output is also a number.

```
//CONTRACT
function isNumber(v) {
  return !Number.isNaN(v) && typeof v === 'number';
}
isNumber.expected = "number";

/**
 * @param preList Array of contracts to check
 * @param post Expected result type as a contract
 * @param f the function
 */
function contract (preList, post, f) {
    //??? No idea
    //precondition
    for (let i = 0; i < preList.length; i++) {  //THIS DOESNT WORK
        let valid = preList[i].call(this, f.arguments[i]);
        if (valid === false) throw "caller's fault";
    }
    //postcondition
    let result = f.call(this, f.arguments);
    if ((post.call(this, result)) === false) throw "library's fault";
}

//EXAMPLE

var mult = contract(
  [isNumber, isNumber],
  isNumber,
  function mult (x, y) {
    return x*y;
  });

//TEST CODE

console.log("First test")
console.log(mult(3, 4));
console.log();

console.log("Second test")
try {
  console.log(mult(3, "four"));
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
console.log();
```

I'm fairly sure a lot of the contract(){} function is wrong and after a lot of trial and error I have ended up here.

**Currently I'm trying to loop through all the preconditions and call them with the arguments of f.  From my understanding, (arguments) refers to the arguments of the current function, but I'm looking for the arguments of f, not of contract.  f.arguments**

I've also tried to do this with JavaScript proxies which can intercept function calls by setting traps for apply and construct but have gotten stuck as well.

Any help and pointers would be greatly appreciated.  Using node.js to run this program.

Comment: When you do `var mult = contract`, you're saving the return value of calling `contract()`, which is `undefined`. Then you proceed to call `undefined` as a function, e.g. `mult(3, 4)`. I'd offer an answer but I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with this code--you might try simplifying your example to show minimally what you're trying to accomplish and what's going wrong, otherwise it looks like you might want to adjust your approach significantly.

Comment: Ah yeah, then in that case I should directly return the function f after checking the parameters.  I'm still clueless on how to check if mult's parameters are numbers using this format though.  I can't deviate too much since this is an assignment unfortunately, which makes it a lot harder for me to understand code.

Comment: I'm not clear on what `f.arguments` is going to be. AFAIK that will also be `undefined` Each function body has an object called `arguments` which you can use, but what you're doing doesn't resemble that. I think you're trying to do and accomplish too many things at once--break your code into small pieces and verify each one is working as expected, for example, write a simple function that can access its arguments as you intend, then integrate that into the larger program. [here's an example](https://repl.it/repls/HappyWelcomeCharmap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the due date has passed, here's my solution.  I wasn't supposed to be returning a value directly, but a function which would return a value after checking the input parameters and the output.

```
function contract (preList, post, f) {
    return function() {
        for (let i = 0; i < preList.length; i++) {
            let valid = preList[i].call(this, arguments[i]);
            if (!valid)
                throw new Error("Contract violation in position " + i + ". Expected " + preList[i].expected + " but received " + arguments[i] + ".  Blame -> Top-level code");
        }

        let result = f.apply(this, arguments);
        if (!post(result))
            throw new Error("Contract violation. Expected " + post.expected + " but returned " + result + ".  Blame -> " + f.name);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```js
"use strict";

function isNumber(v) {
  return !Number.isNaN(v) && typeof v === "number";
}

/**
 * @param preList Array of contracts to check
 * @param post Expected result type as a contract
 * @param f the function
 * @param array: arguments passed to function f
 */

function contract(preList, post, f, args) {
  for (let i = 0; i < preList.length; i++) {
    let valid = preList[i].call(this, args[i]);
    if (valid === false) throw "caller's fault";
  }
  let result = f.apply(this, args);
  if (post.call(this, result) === false) throw "library's fault";
  return result;
}

let mult = function(x, y) {
  let f = function(x, y) {
    return x * y;
  };
  return contract([isNumber, isNumber], isNumber, f, arguments);
};

console.log("First test");
console.log(mult(3, 4));  // 12

console.log("Second test");
try {
  console.log(mult(3, "four"));
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e); // caller's fault
}
```